# Imageuploding on okhttp3 or Retrofit2, how can i get this uri?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I want to make service for imageuploading using retrofit2 or Okhttp3,

**CODE :**

```
public class GreenFragment extends Fragment {

#I omitted onCreateView that is for checking permission and trigger startGallry()

    private void startGallery() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        cameraIntent.setType("image/*");
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == 1000){
                Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
                try {
                    bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), returnUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mImageview.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
            }
        }
        Uri returnUri;
        returnUri = data.getData(); #This is what i want to control

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_post)
    public void onClick(View view) {

        #Here is what i ask, How can i use retrunUri on here? 
        #On Android studio, retrunUri's font color is red, and not works. 
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(returnUri);
        File imageFile = createFileFromBitmap(bitmap);

        RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("name", makeImageFileName() , RequestBody(MediaType.parse("image/png"), imageFile))
                .build();
        PostApiService.uploadFile(body);
    }

# getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) is for get Bitmap from uri, I omitted opts(options)
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getActivity().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, opts);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

#createFileFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) is for making File from Bitmap
    private File createFileFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        File newFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), makeImageFileName());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        return newFile;
    }

#ImageFileName() is for setting filename
    private String makeImageFileName() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        return strDate + ".png";
    }
```

What I want to know is how to use `returnUri` which is from `onActivityResult`, in `public void onClick(View view)`?

I want to use `returnUri` in `public void onClick(View view)`.

I used an example which is from youtube, but it's too hard for me to understand perfectly, 
So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify the onActiivtyResult then handle the Exception in OnClick

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == 1000){
            Uri returnUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
            try {
                bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), returnUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mImageview.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
        }
    }

    returnUri = data.getData(); //This is what i want to control

}
Uri returnUri;
```